# Records being sent to Kinesis Firehose are shown in Kibana in delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm sending my logs to Kinesis Firehose using the API (C#). The Kinesis is sending it to Elasticsearch and I'm analyzing this data using Kibana.
For some reason, I see the records in Kibana in delay of few minutes (2-5).
I don't know in which step the delay is. 
Why is it taking so long to the data to appear?

Comment: When you set up your Firehose you specified [buffer size and buffering interval](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-deliver.html#frequency). What are they set to?

Comment: @kdgregory - You right. It was 300 sec. I changed it few hours ago to 60 and now the delay is ~1 minute. I forgot to add the answer, i'll do it now. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the 'ES buffer interval (sec)*' in the stream details from 300 to 60.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is kibana.. I have tried it in past and was not much impressed. Can you enable AWS X-Ray .. That can give you visibility into which component is taking so long.